# Elasticsearch installation error: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, plugins, elasticsearch, installation

I'm using a linux machine. The Elasticsearch installation guide told me to simply download and unzip the file, and then run `bin/elasticsearch`. But when I ran it, I got this error:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch
-bash: bin/elasticsearch: No such file or directory
```

I can clearly see the elasticsearch file in my home directory, and all the files within it seem intact. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access the file with:

```
bin/elasticsearch
```

You get the error.

Try to tell the full route.

First move to the directory with cd

```
cd route/to/your/directory
```

Then use `.` for calling from your actual position:

```
./bin/elasticsearch
```

Note: If you get an error about the access or something similar, try giving execution permission to your file:

```
chmod u+x ./bin/elasticsearch
```

Comment: I moved it into Downloads and then cd'd into Downloads and ran `./bin/elasticsearch` but got the same error, `-bash: bin/elasticsearch: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Did you really have that file? Did you uncompressed the file? Maybe your download is corrupted, I Just downloaded the elasticsearch-1.3.4 in tar.gz and it worked without problems.

Comment: That's really weird...Yeah I can cd into Elasticsearch and all it's subfiles from Downloads. I downloaded again and same problem.

Comment: My Last idea is using `[tab] ` for bash suggestion. That could help

Comment: What does that do? Do you mean the tab button or literally "[tab]"?

Comment: Tab button/key is asking bash for suggestions on files OR commands

Answer (score 2):

In the command prompt go to the extracted_file_location/elastic_search_folder/elasticsearch-(some_version_number)_folder.

Now execute bin/elasticsearch

As an example. The extracted file is in downloads with version 8.7.0:

cd Downloads/elasticsearch-8.7.0-linux-x86_64/elasticsearch-8.7.0

Now execute
bin/elasticsearch